# remove replication from a database.

Tags: sql, replication

I am removing replication from a database.  Can this be done with users logged into and using the database? or, will it cause the sql server to have to reboot?

Comment: you should inform/tag which rdbms are you referring in your question.

Comment: You might want to ask this question in: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am using SQL 2000.  I am moving the replicated database to another server and need to break replication.  I believe I understand the steps, but am not sure if the dropping replication is intrusive...should all users be logged off?